# Help finding functions to different graphs

Tags: functions

how would a draw those functions present in this picture? (https://ibb.co/5j6pF4P) I obviously managed to add the linear plot but I don't know how to plot the other three functions. Which functions do I need to get the same result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You ask how to *plot* three functions, when what you provide to identify  those functions **is their plots**? The way to plot them is to draw the graph you provided.